# adding PHP URL with the get method to a JQUERY code

Tags: php, jquery

Please friends is it possible to pass a URL with a get variable in a jquery code like this:

```
$('#show').load('active_chat.php?id=$id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?: `$('#show').load('active_chat.php?id=<?php $id ?>')`

Or do you mean in Javascript?: `$('#show').load('active_chat.php?id=' + id)`

Comment: I tried the both of them but it didn't work. I have a php variable called $id which is queried from database so I want to load mypage.php so I can use the $_GET to get the id of each $id

Comment: Then you need to provide some more information about your code. It is pretty difficult to know what you want to achieve. But judging from what you write, the first one should work. Otherwise you have to provide more code.